# ¿Si algo puede ser verdadero o falso entonces es...?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

- Si algo puede ser coleccionado entonces es *coleccionable*.
- Si algo puede ser modificado entonces es *modificable*.
- Si algo puede ser usado entonces es *usable*.

¿Y si algo puede ser cierto o falso? ¿No tenemos en español una palabra para esto?

He buscado por internet y encontrado la palabra "verificable" pero esta palabra en realidad no significa "tener la capacidad de ser verdadero o falso" sino más bien "tener la capacidad de poderse verificar".

Si verifico algo es porque ese algo es verificable o, lo que es lo mismo, que se puede verificar, pero no que pueda ser cierto o falso.

La razón por la que estoy buscando esa palabra es para describir lo que es una premisa en mi programa informático. `p V q ^ ¬r -> s`. Ese tipo de premisas (lógica de premisas, algo que enseñan en las escuelas en Filosofía de Bachillerato).

Para que entendáis un poco mejor el contexto voy a explicar algo un poco básico de programación:
El caso es que si una moneda es coleccionable en mi programa escribiría algo como `Moneda implements Coleccionable`, lo que significa que una moneda implementa las características propias de las cosas que son coleccionables. Entonces luego puedo escribir en mi programa algo como `moneda.obtenerRareza()` y así podría saber cómo de rara es la moneda en cuestión. Pero estoy buscando algo que vaya bien con `Premisa`.

`Premisa implements XXX` para después hacer algo como `premisa.esVerdadera()`. Reconozco que esto es una enorme e innecesaria perdida de tiempo, pero buscar la palabra adecuada es un problema que en realidad afecta mucho más a los informáticos de lo que parece. Es que es demasiado ridiculo por ejemplo `Premisa implements CapacidadDeSerCiertoOFalso` (No se pueden usar espacios, así que es bastante comun usar mayúsculas y minúsculas para distinguir diferentes palabras).

Comment: Visto que se trata de informática, ¿no podrías referirte a esto como a un valor booleano? ¿O decir que es "evaluable como booleano"? Creo que entiendo lo que quieres decir, pero la forma de expresarlo puede ser muy diferente según el contexto en que se deba usar.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Es una pregunta interesante pero tal vez no puedas encontrar la palabra porque no siempre partes del mismo sitio. Fíjate que _coleccionado_, _modificado_ y _usado_ son participios, mientras que _cierto_ y _falso_ (o "ser cierto o falso") no lo son, por lo que no se puede seguir el mismo procedimiento. En todo caso, intentaremos dar una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: @pablof76 Un dato curioso: a pesar de lo que parezca en realidad uno de los mayores problemas de la informatica no es pensar en un algoritmo que la maquina pueda seguir para hacer un programa, sino pensar en una forma de diseñar el algoritmo de tal forma que otros informaticos puedan entenderlo mas facilente, de modo que se suele pasar mas tiempo en pensar que palabras usar para nombrar las cosas que usarlas. Se siente muy incomodo usando algo como "EvaluableComoBooleano" pero de todos modos en realidad no es algo demasiado importante el nombre que use, solo preguntaba por curiosidad.

Comment: ¿Como se llama algo que puede ser _coleccionado_ y _no coleccionado_ a la vez? Yo creo que la principal dificultad de tu preguntas es que estás tratando de derivar una palabra a partir de otra que no existe... (no sé si me explico).

Comment: *Binario.  Blanco o negro.*

Comment: Me quedo con "binario", como ha señalado @aparente001. Creo que es la respuesta correcta en este contexto. Pero por aportar algo, otra palabra que puedes explorar es "dicotómico".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En lógica se toman una serie de premisas y a través de ella se intenta llegar a una conclusión.

`p -> p` sería el caso más fácil: dada una premisa `p`, siempre podemos deducir `p`. Es decir: si hay agua, hay agua; si no hay pan, no hay pan. La cosa se puede complicar tanto como queramos, pero no es lo que queremos discutir aquí.

Hablas de predicado, pero este es *una expresión lingüística que puede conectarse con una o varias otras expresiones para formar una oración* (de la Wikipedia en [Lógica de primer orden](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_de_primer_orden)). Es con la unión de uno o varios predicados que creamos un argumento lógico:

- si llueve, el suelo está mojado (`p -> q`).
- no está mojado, luego no ha llovido (`¬q -> p`).

Por tanto, lo que entiendo que quieres formalizar en tu [clase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clase_(inform%C3%A1tica)) es el conjunto de premisas junto con su conclusión, para luego indicar si esa conclusión es **deducible** o no. También podemos estar buscando si esa construcción lógica es válida o no, luego podemos estar determinando su *validez* por lo que podrías estar hablando de si es ***validable*** (a pesar de que es una palabra que la RAE no recoge).

También puede ser... **verificable**:

> [**verificable**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=beFBp8s)
>   1. adj. Que se puede verificar.
>   2. adj. Fil. Dicho de una proposición: Que permite comprobar su verdad y examinar el método por el que se ha alcanzado.
>
> [**verificar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=beGg9NJ)
>   Del lat. tardío *verificāre*.
>   1. tr. Comprobar o examinar la verdad de algo.

Comment: Gracias pero no es la palabra que busco exactamente.

Comment: @4dr14n31t0rTh3G4m3r ¿comprobable, demostrable, constatable, revisable?

Comment: @4dr14n31t0rTh3G4m3r ¿certificable? A fin de cuentas "certificar" y "cierto" comparten la misma raíz.

Answer (score 4):

A riesgo de ser tautológico con respecto a la respuesta de fedorqui y a los comentarios, yo creo que podría servirte

> **[falsable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HYgZLqa)**
>
> 1. adj. Que se puede falsar (‖ desmentir).

Answer (score 3):

Si no te importa que la palabra no aparezca en el DLE, podemos usar ***binarizable***.

En tratamiento de imágenes se dice "binarizar una imagen" cuando todos sus píxeles se convierten a solamente dos valores posibles. Así, si entendemos "binarizar" como "asignar un valor de entre dos posibles a una variable", entonces algo que puede ser *binarizado* ("asignado el valor *cierto* o *falso*") es *binarizable*.

Answer (score 2):

Algo que puede ser cierto es *posible*.

Pero la pregunta es acerca de algo que puede ser verdadero o puede ser falso. Es decir, se desconoce cual de las dos posibilidades ocurre. Entonces puedes usar *incierto*.